# Cannot find x264 codec device for FFmpeg transcoding

Tags: c, audio, video, ffmpeg, codec

I am messing around with an FFmpeg transcoding tutorial (source: https://ffmpeg.org/doxygen/trunk/transcoding_8c-example.html)

I am using FFmpeg 4.0.5 and built it successfully as follows:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libx264-dev
$ cd ffmpeg-4.0.5
$ ./configure --prefix=buildout --enable-shared --disable-static --disable-doc  --enable-gpl --disable-opencl --enable-libx264
$ make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo ldconfig
```

I have been looking at an article as well for guidance. (http://www.programmersought.com/article/71051173025/;jsessionid=2D01469BCFABF65530FCC81DBC04E9C0)

The **transcoding.c** source file does compile:

```
$ gcc transcoding.c -o out -lavformat -lavcodec -lavutil -lavfilter
```

Calling the executable is straight-forward:

```
$ ./out $INPUT_VIDEO $OUTPUT_VIDEO
```

where *$INPUT_VIDEO* is an mp4 container (h264/aac)

Up until this point everything appears to be working on my Debian 10 VM (if that is relevant). However, I get the following erroneous output:

```
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x564f664eebc0] Could not find a valid device
[h264_v4l2m2m @ 0x564f664eebc0] can't configure encoder
Cannot open video encoder for stream #0
Error occurred: Invalid argument
```

The article I attached says I need to add it when compiling FFmpeg, so I changed the *./configure* line to as above, but to no avail. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

Comment: Don't know whether it's still true, but you used to have to add an option to the `ffmpeg` program to allow it to use the [patent encumbered] H.264/X.264 codec(s). They were classified as "experimental". To use such a codec, you had to add `--sout-ffmpeg-strict=-2`

Comment: Nope, that unfortunately is not a ./configure option in FFmpeg 4.0.5

Comment: Glad you solved your problem. The option I cited wasn't a config option [when building]. It was an option passed on the command line for each invocation.

Comment: @CraigEstey the option you suggest looks like a VLC option. It certainly isn't an ffmpeg option. Also, ffmpeg's `-strict` is based on spec compliance, not patents..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! My ./configure options were incorrect.

Had to use:

```
$ ./configure --enable-shared --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl
```